# Missing hash prefix error in MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I am getting

```
Error: [$location:ihshprfx] Invalid url "http://localhost:3000/#", missing hash prefix "#!". http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$location/ihshprfx?p0=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%23&p1=%23
```

after `delete` function:

```
$scope.delete = function(venue) {
  venue.$remove();
};
```

but venue is successfully removed. What could be wrong?

UPDATE: I saw that in a dropdown I wrote href = '#' . But when I delete it, nothing happens. How I can call directive from a tag?

```
  <a href='#' ng-click="remove(venue)">Delete</a>
```

Comment: What happens when you set `href=""` on the element?

Comment: `<a ng-click="remove(venue)">Delete</a>` with no `href` should be fine

Comment: I rename the function as delete, an now it is working

Comment: @Burak Would you accept the answer that I posted before your above comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-click` calls a function called `remove` while your scope method is titled `delete`. Because it can't find the function you've set, I believe Angular doesn't to prevent the default event, which sends the user to '#', which is not valid based on your hash prefix settings.

If you match the function call to the method name, I think you should be fine.